# destructuring of large objects when using map with typescript

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I'm still relatively new to typeScript and struggle quite a bit with annotations in a project I work on with various data from a GraphQL endpoint.

The data structure may change later on, so I have used Apollo Client to generate the appropriate TypeScript types for the various queries to avoid typing them manually. This works well: So far so good!

However, when I want to map over the various data I struggle: Mainly when I use the map() function and start destructuring data I have a hard time finding examples on how to do this? I am unsure if I am running into name collisions? The various errors aren't clear to me.

Example: (this is a snippet of a larger code-block - if I hover seoDataObject I can see it is annotated correctly as expected - it is an array of objects:

const seoDataObject: (AllUsersSeo_users_edges | null)[] | null | undefined)

```
interface AllUsersSeo_users_edges {
  __typename: "RootQueryToUserConnectionEdge";
  /**
   * The item at the end of the edge
   */
  node: AllUsersSeo_users_edges_node | null;
}

const seo = seoDataObject?.map(({ node }) => node).find((node) => node.id === id)?.seo;
```

I then get the following error:

```
var node: any
Property 'node' does not exist on type 'AllUsersSeo_users_edges | null'.ts(2339)
```

How would I rewrite this using typescript?

'node' does exist on each seoDataObject - but in the code snippet 'node' is also a parameter in the map function, so I simply cannot wrap my head around how to do this correctly in Typescript?

Comment: I limited this one greatly - it is actually just a minor thing. It comes down to the annotations that ApolloClient is providing:

```
edges: (AllUsers_users_edges | null)[] | null;
```
if I manually change this definition and remove 'or null' annotation the error disappears:

```
edges: (AllUsers_users_edges)[] | null;
``` 

But how can I rewrite this to exclude null values? can conditional” operator be used here?

```
const seo = seoDataObject?.map(({ node? }) => node).find((node) => node.id === id)?.seo;
```
I know this is wrong (node?) - but not sure to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite able to follow what you're really asking, do you just want to find `seo` by id, and it might be in the results, which might be an array of null values, or null itself?

In that case `const seo = seoDataObject?.filter(x => x.node).find(x => x.node.id === id)?.node.seo;`

Comment: Yeah, I am really sorry this is so messy! 
When Apollo-Client is providing annotations they all have this 'or null' annotation ( | null). I will re-download new JSON objects from the Apollo client, so I can't manually edit the annotation. 
When working my way down the objects I normally just use optional chaining (.?) to account for this - but struggle with this when using map(). But maybe filter() is the way around this problem - I didn't think so far - I will have a go at that and see how it plays out!

Comment: Andreas, I used your solution slightly modified:

```
const seo = seoDataObject.filter(x => x?.node).find(x => x?.node?.id === id)?.node?.seo;
```
But I had to turn to the Non-null assertion operator (!) in a few instances to tell typescript that the data is not null or undefined. The code would throw an error a few lines previously if data is null or undefined. I will write a few tests to check that GraphQL data is present also.

An example I did on the previous line:

```
const seoDataObject = seoData?.data?.users?.edges!;
```    

Thanks for helping out Andreas!